# With google forms and scripts is it possible to create a script which will limit the amount of points that user can give in all scale inputs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form with 10 scale questions going from 1 to 10. I would like to give each user 30 points and if they select more than 30 totaling on all scales, disable the submit button and show notification.

I have added a script trough Tools->Script editor, but cannot find an example or trigger which would give me that kind of functionality.

Is it possible, or I have to write my own form template with custom javascript?

Tnx in advance

Comment: What have you already tried? [See this article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hej!
I've checked the google apps script [documentation ](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/), but cannot find any mention of changing user interface while user is filling out the form. Only events I can see in the docs are linked to opening and post-processing of the form after submit. So either I'm missing the concept of google scripts for forms or just having a bad search day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps Scripts on Forms run in either the form editor or on the form submit.  They do not run on the live form.

You could intercept the submit with the onSubmit trigger and check the values of the sliders, inform of the error, and have the user edit their answers.

When the users meets your criteria you can use the .submit() method to commit the checked response.