# Validate Google Form values and prevent submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have two questions in a google form (they are linear scales from 1 to 10).

I also have to validate that both answers combined cannot be different than 10 (for example: 2 and 8 = 10, or 6 and 4 = 10).

If the end-user enters for instance: 9 and 9 = 18, I have to trigger an error on the screen and prevent the submission of the google form.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The tags you chose are not appropriate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With google forms and scripts is it possible to create a script which will limit the amount of points that user can give in all scale inputs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832126/with-google-forms-and-scripts-is-it-possible-to-create-a-script-which-will-limit)